# wordpress / jpegs not showing in rss feeds

Tags: wordpress

I've set up a site with Wordpress with a pretty standard template. the site is functioning well so far, except that some of the pics don't appear when accessed thru the blog's rss feeds... it's also a bit random , no problem with Opera feed reader for instance but in Google reader, some pics are displayed and some others not.

if i clicked on the link of a pic which doesn't display , i get a "you're not authorized to access...." error . i've verified the permissions from the wp-content/uploads/2009/-month- and all the directories are set to 755 , whilst the pics' permissions are set to 644 , which seems adequate...

if i go back to the blog, check a post with pics and click on one of them , the selected pic opens in a new window, now if i compare this url to that of the same pic from an rss feed, it's exactly the same but the url coming from the rss displays an error!!!

so far, i have only tried to use feedburner.com but this hasn't made any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have hotlink protection turned on? If you copy the URL of the picture and paste it into your browser window manually, does it load?

When you say the url opens in a new window, is it opening the picture or a page (or javascript) version with the picture?

When you say you use feedburner, what do you mean? Feedburner will process your RSS feed, but it should display it the same to Google Reader (who owns Feedburner) as Opera. The difference is Opera opens the picture directly, while Google Reader opens the photo from another website, which can have problems with those who installed hotlink protection.

Comment: thanks , i will check this out.

when i say the url opens in a new window, i meant to say that the url opens and the jpeg is displayed.

i mentioned feedburner because i couldn't tell if it was a feed issue or a site issue, therefore by using feedburner i was hoping for some magic operating on the feeds :)

in any case, thanks for your reply, will come back to confirm if this works or not

Comment: i remember doing something about hotlinking but not what i did to prevent it :(

is this the  part of the .ht access file we're concerned with?
<pre>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?myblog\.net/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?google\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [F]
</pre> 

isn't preventing hotlinking a good thing? if yes, is it a choice between not being able to display pics in other blogs (with hotlinking disabled ) or enable hotlinking and have the server drained by other users...?

Comment: Disabling hotlinking will also disable web-based RSS readers from loading your images up. I would recommend turning off hotlink protection, or only enable for certain hosts that are actually hotlinking your images. Unless you are a high traffic site it shouldn't be a problem.